# Rails: Forcing form tag to use an HTTPS action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ssl, https

Trying to use the form_tag helper in rails to submit to an SSL address.  Currently, my code looks like this:

```
form_tag(form_action_path) do
# This spits out:
<form action="form_action_path" method="post">
```

If I try this:

```
form_tag(form_action_path, :protocol => 'https', :only_path => false)
# It spits out:
<form action="form_action_path" method="post" protocol="https" only_path="false>
```

That is of course, not a valid or worthwhile result.  How can I make the form tag helper render out an https action path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the wrong syntax.

Instead of

```
form_tag(form_action_path, :protocol => 'https')
```

I needed

```
form_tag(form_action_url(:protocol => 'https'))
```

The difference being, apparently, that form_action_path generates something like "/path/to/action" and form_action_url generates "http://url.com/path/to/action."

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [SSL_Requirement](http://rubygems.org/gems/ssl_requirement) with your create/update actions. It seems SSL_Requirement is older (not that it needs to be updated, it's not terribly complicated), but there may be a newer gem/plugin that people prefer now.